# Writing a formula for a spread sheet that can solve for a given value

Tags: functions

For instance if given values are $f(1.1) = 1$, $f(1.9) = 2$, $f(2.7) = 3$, $f(3.5) = 4$, $f(4.3) = 5$ and ever increasing by $0.8$ for each number, if I were to enter a value of $1.5$ the answer is $1.5$ but if I enter $2.3$ the answer is $2.5$ what is a formula that would express this?

Comment: sorry i  did not understand question,is it about rounding number?

Comment: i think you can search about ceil and floor function

Comment: no not rounding its a specific gravity problem at a reading of 0 I get 0 at 1oz per gallon I get sg of 1.1 at 2oz per gallon I get 1.9sg at 3oz per gallon I get 2.7sg, the sg goes up by .8 from this point on, I need a formula so I can calculate the oz per gallon from any specific gravity reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your required formula should be $$f(x)=\frac{x-0.3}{0.8}$$

Comment: Thank you Vincent great work. much appreciated works like a charm.